# 'dict' object has no attribute 'int' when imported as module

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda

If in my script I type the following, I get the correct output.

```
test = 'int'
print(getattr(__builtins__, test))
#<class 'int'>
```

However if I create another script named `builtin.py` which contains the same and try to import it, the function does not work.

```
import builtin as b
```

> AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'int'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frame it in Main method
It will work:-

```
if __name__ =="__main__":
    test = 'int'
    print(getattr(__builtins__, test))
```

Comment: All right, that works! But I have this line as part of a method in a class, so I am unsure how to incorporatre the `if`.

Comment: I am not sure but try once with "repr"

Comment: Could you explain me why the `__main__` works? I tried the `repr`, but I am not sure whether it was correct. Anyway, I accepted your answer since it solved the question.

Answer (score 2):

This is what solved it for me:

```
import builtins

test = 'int'
print(getattr(builtins, test))
```